# How to display data from API in React.js

Tags: reactjs, api

I have an api in that returns a result like:

`[[{"AG":2707}],[{"AR":398}],[{"AI":28}],[{"BL":1085}],[{"BS":1318}],[{"BE":2964}],[{"GL":206}],[{"GR":845}],[{"JR":256}],[{"LU":1855}],[{"NW":297}],[{"OW":307}],[{"SH":307}],[{"SZ":1118}],[{"SO":945}],[{"SG":2029}],[{"TI":2146}],[{"TG":1038}],[{"UR":107}],[{"VS":1237}],[{"ZG":3714}],[{"ZH":8496}]]`

So I want those data to display for example:

`AG : {DATA.AG}` => (there to be number 2707)
`AR : {DATA.AR}` => (there to be number 398)

I am new to react and I couldn't find a solution. What can I try next?

Comment: Your first data structure does not seem to be a data structure at all - it is 22 separate Array objects. However I wonder if they appear in a single overall Array object, and you just have not shown that bit.

Comment: I have retagged the question, since you do not seem to be having trouble with Fetch or Axios - you have a return data structure and wish to decode it. That is not a React question either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your data is inside an array so you cannot access it this way in an array, you should have to change your data from array type to object something like this,

```
const data = {
  AG: 2707,
  AR: 398,
  AI: 28,
  BL: 1085,
  BS: 1318,
  BE: 2964,
  GL: 206,
  GR: 845,
  JR: 256,
  LU: 1855,
  NW: 297,
  OW: 307,
  SH: 307,
  SZ: 1118,
  SO: 945,
  SG: 2029,
  TI: 2146,
  TG: 1038,
  UR: 107,
  VS: 1237,
  ZG: 3714,
  ZH: 8496,
};
console.log(data.AG)
```

But If you are strict to use the above data array you can do it something like,

```
const findVal = (key) => {
    let obj = arr.find((el) => el[0][key]);
    if(obj) return arr.find((el) => el[0][key])[0][key]
    return -1;
}

console.log(findVal('AG'))
```